# Can a creature fly and also walk?

Tags: species-identification, ecology

These creatures, fly and walk, and have perfect eyesight and follow me everywhere I go.  They have many legs, they are about 1 inch and their color is almost translucent, but a very light shade of brown.  They smell me at all times and bit me like a mosquito.  I have used 2 pesticide companies to exterminate, but no one is able to identify the critter so I can't kill them.  They also have a very strong heartbeat. I know because they like to be under me.  They move so quickly that I haven't been able to catch a picture.  Please help me to identify these nasty things, so they can be destroyed.

Comment: Sounds like a puzzle! It is going to be impossible to ID this species without more info and probably without a picture. Where do you live? How come you know they have a strong heartbeat but did not manage to take a picture?!